# Is there any benefit of encryption if the password is known?

Tags: encryption, aes

Is there a benefit of encryption of a file (for example with AES-GCM), if the password is included alongside the encrypted data?

I know it sounds like a useless question, but I am curious about its side benefits.

For example, maybe it is better to prevent some people from accessing the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A useful example of this might be the way that Windows encrypts any passwords that were stored in Group Policy Preferences using a [publicly available AES key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-gppref/2c15cbf0-f086-4c74-8b70-1f2fa45dd4be). As a result of this, the ability to exact these passwords is well known and is a common technique used by attackers, and there are dozens of tools out there which can be used to do so.

However, although this encryption provides minimal security benefits, it does require that the attacker perform additional steps. As they now need to:

- Work out that the passwords are encrypted.
- Identify the encryption used.
- Exfiltrate the ciphertext from the system OR introduce a tool into the environment that can decrypt it.

The first two steps are fairly trivial, but the third step *may* be more difficult, particularly in highly restricted environments.

Encrypting a file also sends a clear message that people are not meant to access to it - in much the same way that a "no entry" sign on a closed door makes it clear that people shouldn't go through it. And while that won't stop malicious actors, it makes it much harder for them to try and argue that they didn't realise what they were doing is wrong (which in turn may make it easier to prosecute them under something like the Computer Misuse Act, where there is a requirement to demonstrate intent).

It's certainly not a good security control, and in most cases it will be fairly trivial for an attacker to work around. But I would argue that it's better than just storing the clear text passwords in the Group Policy XML files with no protection at all, as it may prevent some casual and unskilled attackers, and may (slightly) slow down others.

**However**, the big danger with this kind of system is that it may create a false sense of security, as people may think that the data is safe because it's encrypted. Perhaps if this encryption hadn't been proposed then the (insecure) functionality would never have been introduced in the first place, or it would have been more quickly identified as a serious security issue and deprecated.

Comment: So if the processing power needed to encrypt the data is ignored, it can be better to always encrypt it and just attach the password as clear text, with the data?

Comment: @Okoba like most people in security, I'm very hesitant about the word "always". It adds complexity and can create a false sense of security - so you need to balance those against the (minimal) benefits it provides.

Answer (score 1):

If password and encryption algorithm are public, then encrypting the data does not provide any security benefit.

But a public key and algorithm is different from the example with the key under the doormat: Here the attacker does not already have the key, but they must first obtain it by a) knowing that the key is under the doormat, b) being physically present at the doormat to obtain the key from there. Also c) there is only the single key and d) retrieving and using the key might be observed by curious neighbors or a security camera. Contrary to this data and encryption key can easily be copied and the attacker which has key, algorithm and encrypted data can decrypt the data without anybody observing that decryption was done and who did it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a benefit of encryption of a file (for example with AES-GCM), if we know the password is known?

There's no benefit gained towards the security concerns of confidentiality<sup>([0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidentiality))</sup> or forgery mitigation<sup>([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication))</sup>.

Besides that it may helpful as a generic public transformation with no specific security guarantees, or with more thought, perhaps as a public random function<sup>([2](https://eprint.iacr.org/2007/229.pdf))</sup>. In the former case, one might invertibly normalize data into a uniform distribution of bits. Or, utilize the associated data<sup>([3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption#Authenticated_encryption_with_associated_data))</sup> field to assign a particular context to the public transformation. Though, because the key is known, there is no guarantee that any such data is legitimate or was authored by a legitimate party.

<sub>***Note:** AES-GCM does not have a standard API that accepts passwords. It accepts symmetric cryptographic keys.*</sub>

Comment: I am trying to understand your point but without understating the paper you attached, it is hard. Can you explain it in a more ELI5 manner?

Comment: @Okoba It sounds like you want to play around with cryptographic tools. So, I'd recommend studying the available tools to learn how to use them correctly. You can also use them incorrectly if you want. In fact, it can be very helpful to use play & experimentation in the process of learning. Obviously, just don't assume they provide **any** security guarantees when you're using them incorrectly (such as making a secret symmetric key public).

Answer (score 1):

I can think of at least one practical use case:

When an application needs to store credentials to be able to access some resource *without user interaction*, then it makes sense to store the credentials encrypted, but the encryption secret needs to be stored somewhere, for example inside the application code.

I think that this is comparable to keeping a key under the doormat: it is not publicly visible, but everyone can find it if they search for it.

However, there's still the advantage that the secret cannot be viewed as easily as if it wasn't encrypted at all. For example, the application may store the credentials in a database. Thanks to the encryption, if someone accesses the database

- they cannot just read the credentials in cleartext
- a colleague behind him cannot inadvertently see the credentials
- it is impossible to decrypt the credentials if they do not also have access to the application

However, if a secret is encrypted with a known key, it is better to think of it as **obfuscated** rather than encrypted.